# Using DFS (depth first), find the density of blocks which density is over %X

Tags: depth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

In my work (some matrix computation), i am stuck with a problem as below:

```
matrix (NxN):   
          xxxx------------------
          xxxx------------------
          ----xxx-x-------------
          ----xx--x-------------
          ---------x--x---------
          ---------xxxx---------
                   xxxx---------
            ......................
```

[image]

I have a 2D adj matrix has pattern of block daigonals (as shown above). Each block can be dense (100%) or sparse (0.01-5%). With these adj matrix and using graph search (DFS), how can I find the block size (begin_row, being_col, end_row, end_col) and also their corresponding density (mod(E)/mod(V))?

I am sure that there is an easy way to find the blocks and density. I am looking for any idea or pseudo-code, I would really appreciate for your time.

Comment: a. [dfs] tag is not about depth first search. Please change it. b. "block daigonals" is not clear to me. Can you clarify ? as always an example is better than words.  c. Can block be connected ? d. How does density come into play ?

Comment: Hi c0der, I am trying to partition a matrix using graph. so i was planning to use dfs to traverse the graph and find the block diagonals. Block diagonals are like islands connected through the diagonal elements. Here is a picture of it: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjq2Lqrl9HbAhXP-lQKHVifDfAQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fmatlabcentral%2Ffileexchange%2F46972-sparse-block-diagonal-concatenation&psig=AOvVaw3u-7-8HuUo-NBNz-RANbJJ&ust=1528997939577533

Comment: Yes, blocks can be connected. now each block can be thought of a subgraph which has V and E. those subgraph can have density too.

Comment: Now, the task I am thinking is like: 1. sub graphing the blocks of that matrix. 2. find the density of the blocks or subgraphs

Comment: can you help about any idea please? i am not finding any good way to implement it.

Comment: You can try traversing with dfs, starting from 0,0. Every time you reach a diagonal vertex with no right or bottom neighbor, store all traversed vertices as a sub graph. (In the picture posted, blocks are "full". In the nxn matrix posted blocks have "holes" in them. Which one represents your case ?) –

Comment: hi c0der, thank you for your reply. my case has holes in them but if i can have idea about the "full" block, i can make it for sparse case too.

Comment: I believe "make it for sparse" is the difficult part. It may be easier if a "hole" has different representation than a 0 out side a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transverse the diagonal to map where each block starts and ends. 
The transverse can be done by dfs or simple loop. 
Then key is detecting a block end. With "full" blocks is is quiet simple as demonstrated in `isCorner` method. 
This method will have to be modified to account for holes.

```
    //test data
    public static int[][] intArray = {
        {1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        {1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        {0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0},
        {0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0},
        {0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0},
        {0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0},
        {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1},
        {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1},
        {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        mapBlock();
    }

    //traverse diagonal to find block start and block end
    private static void mapBlock() {
        //todo check that matrix is nxn

        int[] origin = {0,0}; //dfs start point
        //traverse diagonal
        for(int rowIndex =0; rowIndex < intArray.length ; rowIndex ++) {
            if(isCorner(rowIndex, rowIndex)) { //diagonal row and col index are equal
                int[] target = {rowIndex, rowIndex}; //dfs target
                block(origin, target);
                origin = new int[]{rowIndex+1, rowIndex+1};
            }
        }
    }

    //is intArray[row Index][column Index] a corner 
    private static boolean isCorner(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {

        //corner must be on diagonal
        if(rowIndex != colIndex ) {
            return false;
        }

        //if last row and col it is a corner
        if(((rowIndex+1) == intArray.length) && ((colIndex+1) == intArray.length))  {
            return true;
        }

        //if left and bottom neighbors are empty - it is a corner
        //todo if you blocks have holes this criteria needs to change
        if((intArray[rowIndex+1][colIndex] == 0) && (intArray[rowIndex][colIndex+1] == 0) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static void block(int[] origin, int[] target) {

        System.out.println("block from " +Arrays.toString(origin)+
                " to "+Arrays.toString(target));
        //todo store sub array 
    }
```

Output:

> block from [0, 0] to [1, 1]
>  block from [2, 2] to [5, 5]
>   block from [6, 6] to [8, 8]

(Test it [online](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/EcnLx4YAQQ) )